# MySQL запрос как оптимизировать?

Tags: mysql

Хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли оптимизировать данный запрос ?

```
SELECT s.id as subdivision_id,s.name as subdivision_name,
    pt.id,
    pt.parent_id,
    pt.name,
    COALESCE(( SELECT sum(pn.count_as_norm) FROM p_passport_norma as pn where pt.id = pn.passport_type and pn.subdivision_id = 21), 0) as count_as_norm,
    COALESCE(( SELECT sum(pqq.count_device) FROM p_passport_quantity pqq where pqq.type_id=pt.id and pqq.subdivision_id = 21 ), 0) as count_device, 
    COALESCE(( SELECT sum(pqq.count_charged) FROM p_passport_quantity pqq where  pqq.type_id=pt.id and pqq.subdivision_id = 21), 0) as count_charged,
    COALESCE(( SELECT sum(pqq.count_non_working) FROM p_passport_quantity pqq where  pqq.type_id=pt.id and pqq.subdivision_id = 21), 0) as count_non_working 
FROM p_passport_type pt, subdivisions s where pt.id  = 22 and s.id = 21 
order by  pt.parent_id,pt.id
```

Comment: Ну как минимум сделать JOIN p_passport_quantity и GROUP BY и считать SUM в самом запросе, а не делать пачку подзапросов в одну и ту же таблицу

Comment: Логично. Но не дает ожидаемого результата.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, который вы пробовали